# Additional makefile target with added compiler option in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, qmake, compiler-options

I have several Qt projects with dependencies on each other. Two projects build executables with different purposes (namely my main app and the unit tests) and depend on the same libraries. Those libraries, however, need to be compiled with different compiler settings when build for my unit tests. So suppose my app needs a set of compiler flags and this set of flags should also be the default when compiling the libraries. My unit test app needs another set (or merely an additional set) of compiler flags for the libraries to be set when they are being compiled.

How can I write qmake `*.pro` files so that I can run qmake once and then use the resulting makefile to compile the libraries for both apps in separate runs of make? I was thinking of having the default make targets `debug` and `release` with the 'default' flags and an additional target `test` to build for my unit tests but I seem unable to figure out how to do this. I am stuck with Qt 4.8.

---

Some background: I am programming in C++ and need to create some mock objects for classes defined in the libraries. These classes, however, do not contain `virtual` methods, so I added a preprocessor flag that gets defined to `virtual` when compiling for unit tests and is empty otherwise. This way I can overwrite methods in my mock objects but do not experience the overhead of virtual function calls in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

May be my solution works for you.
I create my divert pro-Files with make-file(s).
Example creating a program in my project tree:
First a simpler makefile fitting to the program:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

BUILD_PATH  := $(shell cd ../../../; pwd)
CONF_PATH   := $(BUILD_PATH)/sources/config
BIN_PATH    := $(BUILD_PATH)/bin
LIB_PATH    := $(BUILD_PATH)/lib
INS_PATH    := /usr/local

MODULES     := core gui widgets printsupport
TARGET      := CCDDataDisplay
TEMPLATE    := app

DEFINES     := 

INCLUDES    := $(BUILD_PATH)/sources/include
LIBS        := -L$(LIB_PATH) -lhrlLib

DESTDIR     := $(BIN_PATH)

MOCS        := MainWindow.h

include $(CONF_PATH)/conf_qmake.mk
```

conf_qmake.mk:

```
QMAKE       := qmake-qt5

HEADERS     := $(wildcard *.h)
C_SOURCES   := $(wildcard *.c)
CPP_SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)

SOURCES := $(C_SOURCES)
SOURCES += $(CPP_SOURCES)
FORMS   := $(wildcard *.ui)

.PHONY: all
all: depdirs
    @echo  -e  "\n\x1b[32;01m Building \x1b[34;01m$(TARGET)\x1b[32;01m in $(shell pwd) ... \x1b[0m"
    @if [ ! -d .build ]; \
    then \
        rm -f qmake.pro; \
        cp $(CONF_PATH)/qmake.pro qmake.pro;\
        mkdir -p .build; \
        cd .build; \
        $(QMAKE) -makefile "MODULES_IN=$(MODULES)" \
        "TARGET_IN=$(TARGET)" \
        "TEMPLATE_IN=$(TEMPLATE)" \
        "DEFINES_IN=$(DEFINES)" \
        "INCLUDES_IN=$(INCLUDES)" \
        "LIBS_IN=$(LIBS)" \
        "DESTDIR_IN=$(DESTDIR)" \
        "SOURCES_IN=$(SOURCES)" \
        "MOCS=$(MOCS)" \
        "FORMS_IN=$(FORMS)" \
        ../qmake.pro >> /dev/null; \
    fi;
    @$(MAKE) -s -C .build;

.PHONY: depdirs
depdirs:
    @$(foreach dir, $(DEPDIRS), $(MAKE) -s -C $(dir);)

.PHONY: install
install:
    @$(MAKE) -s -C .build install;

.PHONY: realclean clean distclean
clean:
    @if [ -d .build ]; then $(MAKE) -s -C .build clean; fi
    @$(RM) *~;
    @$(RM) $$(BUILD_PATH)/include/*~;

realclean:
    @$(RM) -r .build;
    @$(RM) qmake.pro;
    @$(RM) *~;
    @$(RM) $(BUILD_PATH)/include/*~;

distclean: realclean
    @$(RM) $(BUILD_PATH)/bin/$(TARGET);
    @$(RM) $(BUILD_PATH)/lib/lib$(TARGET)*;
```

and last qmake.pro:

```
QT  += $$MODULES_IN

TARGET = $$TARGET_IN
TEMPLATE = $$TEMPLATE_IN

CONFIG += staticlib

DEFINES += $$DEFINES_IN

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
INCLUDEPATH += $$INCLUDES_IN

LIBS += $$LIBS_IN

DESTDIR = $$DESTDIR_IN

SOURCES += $$SOURCES_IN

HEADERS += $$MOCS

FORMS += $$FORMS_IN

unix {
    target.path = /usr/local
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

with this I have only quiet simple makefiles for generating.
The whole project build is done with one makefile on top of the
project tree.

Maybe this helps ...